# Add one eventHandler for every programaticly created TextBlock specifically

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on some windows phone app. I have this code...

```
for (int b = 1; b < 7; b++){

      for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++){

        date = new TextBlock();
        date .Margin = new Thickness(1);
        date .TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        date .FontSize = 15;
        date .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        date .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        date .Tapped += date_Taped;
        string middle= TIME.days[a].ToString();
        if (middle== "0") { middle= ""; }
        date.Text = middle;
        a++;
        Grid.SetRow(date , b);
        Grid.SetColumn(date , c);
        gridDatum.Children.Add(date );
      }

  }
```

I am adding values to grid and at the end i get my colendar the problem here is that i would like to TAP on one of all of this dinamicly created textblocks and navigate myself to page idk. 24.6.2015. any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve... What are you doing in `date_Taped` and why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: This is the calendar that if you will pressed on the textBlock 01.05.2015 in my Grid It will address you on "05/01/2015 page"

Comment: but event handler is just one thats for date.taped i would like to add date.taped with text ="1.5.2015" if that is posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have an easy way to identify the date that corresponds to the tapped `TextBlock`.

You could use the `Tag` property of the `TextBlock` to store the identifying value, and the check it in the `date_Taped` event handler.

```
for (int b = 1; b < 7; b++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
    {
        date = new TextBlock();
        date .Margin = new Thickness(1);
        date .TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        date .FontSize = 15;
        date .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        date .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        date .Tag = new int[] { a, b, c };

        date .Tapped += date_Taped;
        string middle= TIME.days[a].ToString();
        if (middle== "0") { middle= ""; }
        date.Text = middle;
        a++;
        Grid.SetRow(date , b);
        Grid.SetColumn(date , c);
        gridDatum.Children.Add(date );
    }    
}

private void date_Taped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    var a = (textBlock.Tag as int[])[0];
    var b = (textBlock.Tag as int[])[1];
    var c = (textBlock.Tag as int[])[2];

    // Do stuff with a, b and c

    // Do other stuff
}
```

Or... You could use an `Action` to define a dynamically generated delegate for the `Tapped` event.

```
for (int b = 1; b < 7; b++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
    {
        date = new TextBlock();
        date .Margin = new Thickness(1);
        date .TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        date .FontSize = 15;
        date .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        date .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        date .Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(
                            new Action<object, TappedRoutedEventArgs>((o, e) =>
                                {
                                    var x = a;  // You can use the current value of "a" here
                                    // Do stuff with a, b and c

                                    // Do other stuff
                                }));

        string middle= TIME.days[a].ToString();
        if (middle== "0") { middle= ""; }
        date.Text = middle;
        a++;
        Grid.SetRow(date , b);
        Grid.SetColumn(date , c);
        gridDatum.Children.Add(date );
    }    
}
```